# Center text vertically in select

Tags: html, css

## image

[image]

## question

Is there any way I can shift the "Vancouver, BC" text down a little bit so it aligns better with "CITIES" and "CHANGE"?

I know input elements are finicky to style across browsers; it doesn't have to be perfect but if it could work in at least some browsers, that would be great.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/Zz8ph/)

Comment: @bozdoz: Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: It looks perfectly aligned in fiddle (Chrome).

Comment: @Pavlo: Yeah... Chrome looks good. FF is top-aligned and IE is bottom-aligned.

Comment: @mark best option it seems is to remove the height attribute.

Comment: @bozdoz: Then it doesn't look good beside the button :)

Answer (score 2):

Customizing a browser's default rendering of some form elements--especially dropdown select lists--is generally not recommended for a few reasons:

- Your customization options are naturally limited
- It's extremely difficult to get the form element to look the way you want--as you noted, they're finicky
- Even if you can get the input to look the way you want in one browser, its almost impossible to do it cross-browser (I realize you said that's not a concern, but still, it's worth knowing)
- From a usability perspective, customizing the default rendering of a form element almost always reduces the usability of the form somewhat

NOW, all of that being said, if you want more control over the visual styles of your form elements, I'd recommend using a jQuery plugin. Typically these work by hiding the form elements and replacing them with easily-customizable CSS--usually regular ol' unordered-lists--and then sending the user interactions with the unordered lists to the hidden forms. [Here's one you could check out to get started.](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it...I can do this with pure CSS. They're essentially just links anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would adjust the font-size or the height to fix the alignment issue:

```
#city_picker {
    height: 26px;
    font: 19px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

That would make the text about the same size as the select box, and force it to appear aligned.  Otherwise it seems rather difficult if not impossible to adjust styles of the option elements across browsers.

Comment: The thing about that is that I wanted the font-size and height to be the same as the button's.